# How is composting different from regular aerobic decomposition?

Tags: composting, greenhouse-gas-emissions

How is composting different from regular aerobic decomposition in terms of its (negative?) GHG footprint? Or are those the same thing?

Comment: Where's your own research, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular aerobic decomposition"? My understanding is that composting _is_ aerobic decomposition. "Proper" composting should avoid anaerobic conditions, by avoiding packing or compressing too much, adding bulky, carbon-rich elements, and possible turning it.
Maybe composting can be considered "enhanced, assisted, managed" aerobic decomposition, by keeping an eye on nitrogen/carbon ratio, and brining temperature up (but not too much) instead of just leaving it unmanaged.